# How to replace some character in a string which contain unfixed characters

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is like below

```
"value":"my"value"
```

I need to convert it to

```
"value":"my\"value"
```

Some part in this string is fixed,such as

```
"value":"
```

Some part is not fixed. So I think I can treat the string like below:

```
"value":"xx"xxx"
```

The x part is not fixed, I need replace the string to

```
"value":"xx\"xxx"
```

I think I should try regex, and who can help me to build the regex expression

Comment: @CertainPerformance, naturally end? What it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex like this:

```
'"value":"xx"xxx"'.replace(/("value":".*)"(.*")/, '$1\\"$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

res.log

```
{   "key": "name", 
    "value" : "value with" quote", 
}
```

code snippet

```
content = content.replace(/"[^"\\:\n]+"[^"\\:\n]+"/gi, (s) => {
            var substr = s.slice(1, s.length - 1);
            substr = substr.replace("\"", "\\\"");
            return "\"" + substr + "\"";
        });
```

Full Sample function

```
  var fs = require("fs");

    module.exports =  () => {
            let file = 'res.log';
            let content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
            console.log(content);
            content = content.replace(/"[^"\\:\n]+"[^"\\:\n]+"/gi, (s) => {
                var substr = s.slice(1, s.length - 1);
                substr = substr.replace("\"", "\\\"");
                return "\"" + substr + "\"";
            });

            console.log(content);
        };
```